# How to simulate keypress

Tags: c#

I know how to use SendKeys() but how do i go about it if i would like to simulate holding ESCAPE key for like 5 seconds?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I can understand the need of detecting such an event from user input, but why simulate it programatically ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can PInvoke `keybd_event` and hold down Escape key for 5 seconds and then release it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);


keybd_event(VK_ESCAPE, 0, 0, 0) // KEY_DOWN

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

keybd_event(VK_ESCAPE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) // KEY_UP
```

Comment: how do i use/add VK_ESCAPE and KEYEVENTF_KEYUP to my project?

Comment: const int VK_ESCAPE = 27; const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

Comment: ummm... take look at this: http://api.farmanager.com/en/winapi/virtualkeycodes.html

Comment: Im testing a abit, if i replace VK_ESCAPE with VK_A i should get "aaaaaaaaaa" in a textfield if i sleep it X seconds shouldnt i? im just getting one at the time (testing with a Timer loop) U are using KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x02 right?

Comment: `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` should be `2` or `0x02`. I think As you sleep your application thread after holding down A, it won't respond to keybd_event (Thus just one `A` written in the TextBox in your application) . Use a timer or make another thread instead.

Answer (score -2):

try using a timer... use System.Forms.Timer... for 5000ms... then if the 5000ms is finished, shut the timer off..

Comment: Read the question again, this isn't about reading a long keypress, but about sending one.

Comment: I guess he want to programmatically generate something like `KeyDown` and after 5 secs a `KeyUp` event, not sending a KeyPress and wait 5 seconds...